# jQuery animate picture over li with same link as li

Tags: jquery, position, html-lists, mouseover

Basically, I want this sort of functionality but less complicated: http://www.blueacorn.com/team/

I have a ul of various li's containing pictures which will link to a LinkedIn account only (not Twitter as well like in the example). I want it to be that when you hover over one of these pictures, a jQuery animation will display an image over it and you will be able to click on it to go to their LinkedIn. (Eventually these will all be different people's pictures.)

Here's my JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5y64/

If possible, I do NOT want to create an id for each box as I am going to have 40+ of them (and growing).

My main issues are:

1) I cannot get the divHover to properly animate itself on top of the picture I hovered over (it goes all over the place!)

2) I cannot get the divHover to link to different webpages.

I am sure there is a way for me to do this dynamically, but I can't figure it out.

BTW, this question is similar but relies on creating an id for each block: [How to position a hover div based on the position of the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923317/how-to-position-a-hover-div-based-on-the-position-of-the-element)

I haven't really been able to find a good example of this (that I could understand). But the problem is hard to describe, so maybe I missed it.

I am still new to jQuery, so if possible please dumb down your answers. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know that on hover with an automatic transition to the hidden div can be implemented purely in CSS, many examples here (on the speakers page): http://futurem.org
Maybe I can come back to this question tonight if no answers are given.

Comment: I've also noticed that you can use an image called a "sprite", which is a combination of two images, with overflow hidden and absolute positioning when you want to animate the sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a quick example of how i would do it.
Just like on blueacorn, i added the overlay to each li in advance, so there can be multiple of them visible. (if one is still sliding down, others can slide up at the same time).

You also had some problems in your HTML, like `a` around `li`, wich is not allowed.

Here's my example:

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/bYcmc/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img src="http://w3schools.com/css/klematis.jpg" />
            <a href=""></a>
        </div>
        <h6>Name 1</h6>
    </li>
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
        'top': '0%'
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('a').stop().animate({
        'top': '100%'
    }, 300);
})​
```

Comment: I was able to implement this code and everything works perfectly! (Making the <a> a block was a really cool idea, too.)
Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I would take the approach in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hZHKE/2/). The important parts to notice are the relative positioning of the thumbnails and the absolute positioning of the divHovers. Also, notice how there are multiple hover elements created, one for each thumbnail.

**EDIT:** I also made the HTML proper by nesting the `<li>` elements directly inside the `<ul>`, and then from there nesting the anchor tags.

Comment: This is the functionality I want; the only trouble is when hovering over many in quick succession, many get stuck with the image overlay. I'm think there's a way to clear it but I tried .stop().animate() ... with no change.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below code works perfectly as per your requirement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Scroll - Up - Down</title>
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".scroll-up-down li").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).find("span.hover-link").show();
        });

        $(".scroll-up-down li").mouseout(function(){
            $(this).find("span.hover-link").hide();
        });


    });
    </script>
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->

    <!-- STYLES -->
    <style type="text/css">

        body                        { background:#CCC; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
        h1                          { font-size:16px; text-align:center; }
        .scroll-up-down             { border:1px dashed #bbb;  margin:0 auto; padding:0; text-align:center; width:400px; }
        .scroll-up-down li          { display:inline-block; list-style:none; margin:10px; position:relative; text-align:center; width:100px; z-index:999; }
        .scroll-up-down li span.hover-link              { background:url(hover-div.png) no-repeat;
                                                          border:5px solid #000;
                                                          color:#FFF;
                                                          font-size:12px;
                                                          font-weight:bolder;
                                                          display:none;
                                                          height:60px; 
                                                          left:0;
                                                          list-style:none;
                                                          padding-top:40px; 
                                                          position:absolute; 
                                                          filter: alpha(opacity=50);
                                                          opacity: 0.5;
                                                          text-align:center;
                                                          top:0; 
                                                          vertical-align:bottom;
                                                          width:100px; 
                                                          z-index:1000; 

                                    }
        .scroll-up-down li span.hover-link a.linkedin-icon { background:url(linked-icon.png) no-repeat 0 -50px;  display:inline-block; height:40px; width:40px; }
        .scroll-up-down li span.hover-link a.linkedin-icon:hover { background-position:0 0;   display:inline-block; height:40px; width:40px; }
        .scroll-up-down li a span   { font-size:12px; }
        .scroll-up-down li a        { display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; }
        .scroll-up-down li a img    { border:5px solid #000; height:100px;  width:100px; }

    </style>
    <!-- / STYLES -->
</head>

<body>
    <h1> User Profiles Grid</h1>
    <ul class="scroll-up-down">

        <li><a href="mylinkedin.php"><img src="mysteryman.jpg" alt="mystery-man" title="mystery-man" /><span>Mr. ABC</span></a>
        <span class="hover-link"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/aratibhandare" class="linkedin-icon">&nbsp;</a></span>
        </li>

        <li><a href="mylinkedin.php"><img src="mysteryman.jpg" alt="mystery-man" title="mystery-man" /><span>Ms. PQR</span></a>
        <span class="hover-link"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/aratibhandare" class="linkedin-icon">&nbsp;</a></span>
        </li>

        <li><a href="mylinkedin.php"><img src="mysteryman.jpg" alt="mystery-man" title="mystery-man" /><span>Mr. XYZ</span></a>
        <span class="hover-link"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/aratibhandare" class="linkedin-icon">&nbsp;</a></span>
        </li>


        <li><a href="mylinkedin.php"><img src="mysteryman.jpg" alt="mystery-man" title="mystery-man" /><span>Ms. LMN</span></a>
        <span class="hover-link"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/aratibhandare" class="linkedin-icon">&nbsp;</a></span>
        </li>

        <li><a href="mylinkedin.php"><img src="mysteryman.jpg" alt="mystery-man" title="mystery-man" /><span>Mr. DEF</span></a>
        <span class="hover-link"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/aratibhandare" class="linkedin-icon">&nbsp;</a></span>
        </li>

        <li><a href="mylinkedin.php"><img src="mysteryman.jpg" alt="mystery-man" title="mystery-man" /><span>Mr. JKL</span></a>
        <span class="hover-link"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/aratibhandare" class="linkedin-icon">&nbsp;</a></span>
        </li>


        <li><a href="mylinkedin.php"><img src="mysteryman.jpg" alt="mystery-man" title="mystery-man" /><span>Ms. RST</span></a>
        <span class="hover-link"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/aratibhandare" class="linkedin-icon">&nbsp;</a></span>
        </li>

        <li><a href="mylinkedin.php"><img src="mysteryman.jpg" alt="mystery-man" title="mystery-man" /><span>Mr. QWE</span></a>
        <span class="hover-link"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/aratibhandare" class="linkedin-icon">&nbsp;</a></span>
        </li>

        <li><a href="mylinkedin.php"><img src="mysteryman.jpg" alt="mystery-man" title="mystery-man" /><span>Mr. YUI</span></a>
        <span class="hover-link"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/aratibhandare" class="linkedin-icon">&nbsp;</a></span>
        </li>


    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```